# Sorting fields in customer address form edit admin section

Tags: sorting, customer-address

I'm very confused by sorting some fields in customer address edit form.

[image: customer's address form]

I want to move **City** after **State/Province** and **Subdistrict** after **City**. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the customer attibute sort order in `customer_eav_attribute` table

```
//28 is city attribute id
UPDATE `customer_eav_attribute` SET `sort_order`= 100 WHERE `attribute_id` = 28
```

Comment: Really Nice ! Thank you very much. It solved my problem !